# Programmatically push another view controller on top of a DetailViewController on a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having some trouble using a `UISplitViewController`. I have a universal application where I have a `UITabBar` where in one Tab is a `UISplitViewController`. The Controller is (traditionally) collapsed on a phone and expanded on an iPad. The `DetailViewController` has a Button where another `ViewController` (a `ChatViewController`) is pushed on top of the detailViewController.

I want to do the following - I want to programmatically select the tab of the splitviewcontroller (no problem so far) and make the `ChatViewController` visible, i.e. on a phone push the `DetailViewController` on top of the `MasterViewController` and than the ChatViewController on top of the `DetailViewController` and on a Pad only push on the right hand side the `ChatViewController` on top of the `DetailViewController`.

I am using `TWMessageBarManager` to display within the App Push Notifications (i.e. Chat Messages in that case). When the user taps on the bar on the top I want to display the `ChatViewController`.

I am running in several problems:

1. After selecting the tab of the `UISplitViewController` I call a `performSegueWithIdentifier` to have the correct `detailItem` set and `DetailViewController` visible, before pushing the `ChatViewController`. However, the default behaviour is that the `DetailViewController` is pushed with an animation on top of the `MasterViewController` and I do not want that behaviour in this scenario.
2. The view hierarchy of a `UISplitViewController` is different on a tablet and phone and even during runtime. On a tablet (and on the phone, before the view controller was visible) the `DetailViewController` is in the `splitviewcontroller.viewControllers` array at the second position. On a phone, after the splitviewcontroller has shown the first time, the `detailviewcontroller` is in the `masterviewcontroller.navigationcontroller.viewcontroller` array.

Does anyone has a solution for not performing an animated segue within a `SplitViewController` (problem 1) and to get the correct reference of the `detailViewController` (problem 2.)

Best regards
Dominik